# why does my std::transform retuns nothing/empty string?

Tags: c++

can you help explain me how to use `std::transform` ?
I need to create a function that returns a string and has a string as parameter
and use `std::transform` to convert all the uppercase char to lower and vice versa lowercase char to uppercase
example:
input = "aBc"
output = "AbC"

and i want to do it with a lambda, not using other mehtod like toupper, etc.

​​​​​​this is what i have so far which doesnt work, it compiles and runs but it returns nothing/ empty string;

```
std::string func(std::string inputString){
        std::string result;
        std::transform(inputString.begin(), inputString.end(), result.begin(), [](char& c){
                if (c < 97) return c + 32;
                if (c >= 97) return c - 32;
        });
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, the second if-condition is superfluous; that line can be replaced with simply `return c - 32;` Realizing that, the entire function body can be replaced with a ternary expression: `return (c < 97) ? c + 32 : c - 32;`

Comment: I noticed that, I just like to write my code like that, bad habbit I know

Comment: The main reason you should avoid that kind of superfluous specificity is leaving the door open in the future for accidentally introducing a code path with no return-value exit strategy. Definitely want to avoid that.

Comment: Basically you code invokes Undefined Behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/dx5fKehbM and there is more the one UB!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't allocated any space in `result`, so you are observing a pretty "gentle" case of undefined behavior ("gentle" because the program is observably not working, rather than happening to work by pure luck).

To solve the problem, you can either allocate such memory before calling `std::transform`, e.g. via

```cpp
result.resize(inputString.size());
```

or use a [`back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) for `result` (instead of its begin iterator `result.begin()`), which will take care of the allocation; the page on [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) has such an example. In this latter case, it is still probably a good idea to reserve some space via

```cpp
result.reserve/* not resize! */(inputString.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

**The cause of the problem:**
You haven't allocated memory for `result`.

**You can cope with it in one of the following ways:**

1. Allocate memory explicitly using [**`std::string::resize`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) before calling `std::transform`:

```
result.resize(inputString.length());
```

2. Use [**`std::back_inserter`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) instead of `result.begin()` when calling `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(inputString.begin(), inputString.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [](char& c) {
```

**Note:** your lambda's body can be simplified to:

```
    if (c < 97) return c + 32;
    return c - 32;
```

It will also fix a compiler warning (MSVC at least complained that the lambda is not always returning a value).